# Can a Cinder Blame This Puzzle?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> Drive as as fast as you can or give up and park.
>   I am there all the way. I'm a smooth one and dark.
>   I was formed in a blaze like the fires of hell.
>   I am oft underfoot. Overhead, though, as well.
>   Say my alternate name, I took gents in my jaws,
>   But the name I have here tells a snake it must pause.

The answer is a single English word. Please explain all clues and the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current answer is close; I'd say this is

> **Asphalt**

Drive as as fast as you can or give up and park.

> You can drive or park on it

I am there all the way. I'm a smooth one and dark.

> Asphalt stretches all the way and is smooth and dark

I was formed in a blaze like the fires of hell.

> It's made with intense heat

I am oft underfoot. Overhead, though, as well.

> The latter probably refers to overpasses. According to OP, it refers to roofing shingles which commonly contain asphalt.

Say my alternate name, I took gents in my jaws,

> Its alternative name is Bitumen, which looks like **Bit-U-Men**

But the name I have here tells a snake it must pause.

> **Asp+Halt** = Asphalt

The title

> Is a play on **Ash Fault** thanks to @tmpearce.

Comment: Most of the stuff is used for paving but a substantial percentage is used for roofing shingles.

Comment: As for the title: "Cinder blame" -> "Ash fault" perhaps?

Comment: @tmpearce Good one! Hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @tmpearce Correct!

Answer (score 3):

Is it a

> road ?!

Drive as as fast as you can or give up and park.

> Along a road one can drive as well as park

I am there all the way. I'm a smooth one and dark.

> It is there all the way, smooth and black

I was formed in a blaze like the fires of hell.

> Usually made of burning tar

I am oft underfoot. Overhead, though, as well.

> Roads are usually underfoot though flyovers/over bridges are also possible

Say my alternate name, I took gents in my jaws,

> Serpentine

But the name I have here tells a snake it must pause.

> Every(perhaps winding) road has an end

About the title,

> Cinder has a literal meaning of 'ash' and fly-ash is proven to be a material used for construction (of roads as well ?)

Comment: Some good thinking. For the title, what's another word for blame?

Comment: @HughMeyers, got it based on Walt's answer... Another word for blame is 'fault'... which is actually here - "..phalt"..wondering..:-)

Answer (score -2):

> Asphalt (alternate name bitumen)

Comment: Well done! And welcome to Puzzling! I have added a spoiler tag to your answer. If you get down votes, it is because there is already an accepted answer to this question.

Comment: A full answer will explain the reasoning and not just give the solution. Please keep Puzzling!